# Gradle Build fails with new Gradle 3.0.0 and Android Studio 3``

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

So I tried starting a new project from scratch with the new version 3 of Android Studio. Everything works until it tries to build the project. Then I get this error message:

```
Error:Unable to find method 'org.gradle.tooling.model.gradle.GradleBuild.getIncludedBuilds()Lorg/gradle/tooling/model/DomainObjectSet;'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
<a href="stopGradleDaemons">Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li><li>Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.</li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Click on either solution does not keep it from failing again. I even emptied my gradle home folder to no avail. Any ideas why this is failing on a totally new project with nothing but the basic template?

Comment: delete .Gradle folder in c:/Users/YOURFOLDER/

Comment: Did not work @DivyeshPatel

Comment: try to invalidate/cache and reastart android studio and turn off internet for a while

Comment: "turn off internet for a while"?!

Comment: @axtscz did you find a solution for this? I'm getting something similar

Comment: same problem here

Comment: I'm tried upgrade 2.3 to 3.0 met the same problem,so I delete android studio folder and reinstall. this problem fixed.

Comment: I both deleted .gradle and the Android Studio preview folder, and between the two, that fixed it.

Comment: Deleting the .gradle folder in c:/Users/YourFolder did not work and deleting the gradle folder from the project did not work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This happens if you install Android Studio 3 (resp. 3.0.1) into the same folder of an older version.

Just rename (or remove) the old folder and then unzip and install again.

Comment: Worked for me. App was being deployed through Self-Service which didn't bother to first clear out the old directory. Requesting them to do so fixed the issue. 

I believe this is specifically caused by there being multiple gradle/gradle-{version} directories under the app's directory.

Thank you!